# Mixpanel delete user does not delete events

Tags: mixpanel

I'm trying to clean up my mixpanel data. I had test users being tracked so I removed them in order to better understand retention. However, the users are still showing up in the retention report aggregated data.

For example, I only have 138 users in my explore tab but significantly more in the sum of people in the retention report.

Has the event data not been deleted? Or am I missing something? Should deleting the profile cascade delete the associated event data?